# how to upgrade tensorflow after installing it using conda?

Tags: tensorflow, conda

I have installed tensorflow-gpu by

`conda install tensorflow-gpu` and its version is 1.12.0

```
tensorboard               1.12.2           py36he6710b0_0
tensorflow                1.12.0          gpu_py36he74679b_0
tensorflow-base           1.12.0          gpu_py36had579c0_0
tensorflow-gpu            1.12.0               h0d30ee6_0
```

I need to upgrade them to at least 1.13 to use tensorflow/models .

I've looked at `conda search tensorflow` and `conda search -c conda-forge tensorflow` , the highest version is 1.12.0 , how do I upgrade the version?

I installed via conda, because blogs suggest it's easier that way to use gpu.
(https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-installing-tensorflow-using-pip-for-performance-sake-5854f9d9eb0c)

Comment: I'm confused. [I don't see any Tensorflow 1.14](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags). And [TensorFlow/models hasn't had an official release since v1.11](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/releases). I assume you're looking for a **linux-64** build, since the **win-64** platform does have [the latest version (v1.13.1) on Anaconda channels](https://anaconda.org/search?q=tensorflow).

Comment: sorry it's 1.13 not 1.14, I found https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5709 doesn't work with 1.12 (recommendation model doesn't work with 1.12) ... I upgraded using the official pip instruction .. and it now works.. hope it was easier with conda, but there seems to be no 1.13 for conda ubuntu as of now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These actions helped me on Windows:

I removed tensorflow related libraries with the `conda remove tensorflow-gpu tensorboard tensorflow tensorflow-base tensorflow-estimator` command.

Then I checked the latest version: `conda search tensorflow`. It was 1.14.0

So I installed this version: `conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0`

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. While I had tried the `install` command, I found that it does not work unless you remove all `tensorflow`-related packages as you have done.

Comment: You don't have to be removing anything. You can directly go ahead with the installation and it will replace the necessary modules. Same with downgrading too.